# ¿Instale la misma dependencia de forma global y en un proyecto? ¿Ahora quiero ejecutar la local, como especifico que quiero la local y no la global?

Tags: firebase

Instale `firebase-tools` para usar firebase.

Tenia instalada esa herramienta de forma global.

Pero ahora la instale como dependencia de desarrollo.

quiero ejecutar el comando `firebase login` para empezar a usar la herramienta, pero quiero usar la versión que instale de forma local, ¿como puedo indicar que quiero esa versión especifica?.

las dos cosas las he instalado con node package manager (npm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando npx te permite ejecutar binarios de paquetes npm, realizando una prueba para poder tener una respuesta mas elaborada logre realizar el siguiente ejemplo:

```
> mkdir test
> cd test
> npm init -y
```

editar el archivo package.json para que contenga el siguiente script:

```json
"scripts": {
    "firebase-login": "npx firebase login"
 }
```

luego sin instalar nada ejecuta npm run firebase-login y estarás ejecutando el binario global de tu equipo.

fuente [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164863/10776775)